# Batch-File - Interval loop instructions while a certain process is open

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, backup, xcopy

So I'd like to create a batch script to loop a particular set of code, while a certain process is open on the system, where the loop code is run at a 30min interval.

To understand it better, the code is to back up save data of a game while the game is running at a timed interval and stops when the game stops as well.

This is the code I have which is only executed by me. It backs up the last saved data and then launches the game.

```
set currDate=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

xcopy /s /i "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Saved\SavedArksLocal" "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Save Backups\%currDate%\SavedArksLocal"
xcopy /s /i "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Saved\LocalProfiles" "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Save Backups\%currDate%\LocalProfiles"

start "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Binaries\Win64" ShooterGame.exe
```

I'd like to check while the game is still running and at 30min intervals to save the files as shown in my code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to check if the task is open by using the 'tasklist' command (also a timeout command for countdown):

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

timeout /t 1800
rem Mean '1800' secs is 30 mins

set isOpened=false
set process=[enter your process name in here]

For /f "tokens=* skip=3" %%a in ('tasklist') do (
  set dip=%%a
  set dip=!dip:~0,29!
  set dip=!dip: =!
  if "!dip!"=="!process!" set isOpened=true
)
```

The 'isOpened' variable will return 'true' if the process '%process%' is still opened.
Now, you have to add code to check if the game is running it will save, else it will exit (automatically):

```
if "!isOpened!"=="true" (
  rem Here is where you put your code when the process still running:
  set currDate=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

  xcopy /s /i "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Saved\SavedArksLocal" "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Save Backups\%currDate%\SavedArksLocal"
  xcopy /s /i "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Saved\LocalProfiles" "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Save Backups\%currDate%\LocalProfiles"

  start "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Binaries\Win64" ShooterGame.exe
)
if "!isOpened!"=="false" (
  rem Now insert code if process is not running: (only 'goto :eof')
  goto :eof
)
```

Now you done, and here is the whole file (if u want to copy):

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

timeout /t 1800
rem Mean '1800' secs is 30 mins

set isOpened=false
set process=[enter your process name in here]

For /f "tokens=* skip=3" %%a in ('tasklist') do (
  set dip=%%a
  set dip=!dip:~0,29!
  set dip=!dip: =!
  if "!dip!"=="!process!" set isOpened=true
)
  if "!isOpened!"=="true" (
  rem Here is where you put your code when the process still running:
  set currDate=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

  xcopy /s /i "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Saved\SavedArksLocal" "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Save Backups\%currDate%\SavedArksLocal"
  xcopy /s /i "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Saved\LocalProfiles" "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Save Backups\%currDate%\LocalProfiles"

  start "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Binaries\Win64" ShooterGame.exe
)
if "!isOpened!"=="false" (
  rem Now insert code if process is not running: (only 'goto :eof')
  goto :eof
)
```

**NOTE:** Make sure to replace text '[enter your process name in here]' (at top of file) as your process name!

Comment: Your answer helped a lot since I didn't know about timeout and how to use for loops and if statements, but I used your answer and modified it to solve my problem. Thanks a lot. See the answer I posted

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the previous answer. I wanted the code to keep running while the process was on so I put the `:loop` tag and reset the variable values at the start of every loop. I also changed the timeout to 15mins. This code solves my issue. Thanks for the help

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

start "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Binaries\Win64" ShooterGame.exe

:loop
set isOpened=false
set process=ShooterGame.exe

set currDate=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

timeout /t 900
rem Mean '1800' secs is 30 mins

For /f "tokens=* skip=3" %%a in ('tasklist') do (
  set dip=%%a
  set dip=!dip:~0,29!
  set dip=!dip: =!
  if "!dip!"=="!process!" set isOpened=true
)
if "!isOpened!"=="true" (
  rem Here is where you put your code when the process still running:
  set currDate=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
  xcopy /s /i "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Saved\SavedArksLocal" "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Save Backups\%currDate% - auto\SavedArksLocal"
  xcopy /s /i "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Saved\LocalProfiles" "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Save Backups\%currDate% - auto\LocalProfiles"

  goto :loop
)
if "!isOpened!"=="false" (
  rem Now insert code if process is not running: (only 'goto :eof')
  goto :eof
  exit
)
```